# How to reset my 8 Ball Pool account progress?

Tags: android, 8-ball-pool

Is at all possible to reset ones account on 8 ball pool for Android?

I would like to start the game from scratch, but can't find a way to reset my account. I have both my Facebook and Google accounts linked to the game, if that is of any use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sending your request to the 8 ball pool developer at support@miniclip.com